# Making multiple fb.api calls

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, dom-events, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been just starting on Facebook Graph API.

How can I call several attributes with just 1 FB.api call? Right now, I have

```
        FB.api('/me', function(me){
          if (me) {
            var myEmail = me.email;
            var myID = me.id;
            var myFirst_name = me.first_name;
            //Other attributes
          }
        });
```

and

```
        FB.api('/me/friends',{ fields: 'name,id' }, function(response){
            var friends = response.data;
        }
       });
```

How do I combine both API calls into one, like say, just 1 `FB.api()` call?

All responses will really really help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do I combine both api calls into one, like say, just 1 FB.api() call?

You could combine them both into one [Batch Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) – but that’ll make dealing with the response a little more complex, and I’m not sure if it would bring any “performance” gain in such a simple use case anyway.

EDIT:

There is a new way now¹ using the [field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#fieldexpansion) feature:

```
/me?fields=id,email,first_name,friends.fields(id,name)
```

– this would get you the requested fields id, email and first_name for the current user, and also the id and name for their friends. (Actually, just `,friends` would do if you only want their id and name, because those are the default fields the API delivers – but if you want other fields as well, you can add them using `,friends.fields(…)`.)

---

¹ actually for quite a while now, but this question has come to my attention again now, so I thought I’d add that.